# Is code coverage included with Visual Studio Team Services (Visual Studio Online) packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, code-coverage, azure-devops

Is code coverage supported with Visual Studio Team Services by default, and can the team check the coverage result on their local visual studio instances? (coloring the coverage).

Comment: If we need to supported on our local instance, we would require an enterprise license of VS.

Comment: You can get C# Test Coverage tools that do not require Enterprise versions of VS to run or display.  See, for example, tools offered by my company: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html

Comment: You can get coverage reports for free with OpenCover. I've explained how to do this on my blog: http://codewithstyle.info/setting-up-coverage-reports-on-vsts-with-opencover/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, when you add "Visual Studio Test" step in your build definition, you can check the "Code Coverage Enabled" option:
[image]

And then you can see the code coverage information in the build report:
[image]

You can also download the code coverage results file into your local machine but you need to use VS Enterprise edition to open it.